# My app have multiple users who can generate invoice for customer, but all users get the same invoice no at the time of billing

Tags: codeigniter

Hi, I have developed a billing web app in Codeigniter and it's working fine for a single user.

But, this web app is designed for multiple users who can generate the bill for the customer, but when the users start the invoice page it displays the same invoice no for all the users, and only the 1st user is able to add the invoice correctly, rest of other user end up with an error and they can not be able to add the invoice...Please help me I am a new developer and I am not able to figure out how to resolve this error. Thanking you in advance.

**This is the code to Generate Invoice No**

```
function showinvno(){ 
        $cfy = date('y');
        $value2 = '';
        $inv = 'sshos'.$cfy."00000";
        $invno = $this->db->select('invno')
                ->from('invoice')
                ->get();
        foreach($invno->result() AS $row){
            $value2 = $row->invno;            
        }
        if($inv <= $value2){
            $value2 = substr($value2, 7, 12);//separating numeric part
            $value2 = $value2 + 1;//Incrementing numeric part
            $value2 = 'sshos'.$cfy. sprintf('%05s', $value2);//concatenating incremented value
            $newID = $value2; 
        } else{
            $value2 = 'sshos'.$cfy."00001";
            $newID= $value2;
        }
        return $newID;
    }
```

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAINC.jpg)

Please help me.....

Comment: add some uniqe id using md5(uniqid($your_user_login_id, true))

Comment: how do I let the app know that a user is generating a bill and it has not to use the same invoice no for other users and maintain the sequence of the invoice no. Do I need to use the cache or something else...I have no idea

Comment: Please provide some insight into my question. real code is not required, just a hint on how to proceed.

Comment: invoice is generating in app side or web side

Comment: if u generating invoice on web side and to notify app u can use push notification or send some statuses.